# What is SpaceChem's shortcut key for pausing?

Tags: spacechem

The keys <kbd>1-4</kbd> are for speed, <kbd>~</kbd> is for reset, but what key pauses the execution/chemflow?

Comment: It's been a while since I played this, but I thought it was space or enter, or something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BlueRaja's comment is correct, the shortcut key for pause is space.

Comment: @CyberSkull Seems to answer the question fine to me. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: When this came up on review I thought this was a post commenting on another post.

Comment: That message is the automated reply generated by the review tool. I didn't even know it left messages.

Comment: @CyberSkull It doesn't do anything *but* leave a canned comment.